# Woocommerce - WordPress Roles & Capabilities

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a WordPress user and I am assigning him the "Shop manager" role which is automatically created by Woocommerce.

However, I have an issue that when this user is logging into the WP admin, he is not seeing the "All Products" and "Add New" menu items under the Products option.

I have tried installing the plugin "Members" which is suggested by WooCommerce (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/roles-capabilities/) and noticed that this role indeed is granting the user to almost all capabilities for WooCommerce. Did anyone ever encounter this issue? Is there a way to allow this user to see the "All Products" and "Add New" menu items even though he is not an administrator?

**Edit:**
Below you can see the capabilities granted for products.  Similarly, all other capabilities for refunds, orders, and anything related to WooCommerce is granted.
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the Access plugin, you can create more fined grained access control and achieve better administration of your site.
Use the following steps to create your own roles with custom permissions for Woo-commerce.
1. Create a custom role.
2. Click on Change permissions for that role, click on Woo-commerce capabilities to display related ones and grant the manage_woo-commerce capability. This capability is required if you want the role to have access to any Woo-commerce administration screen.
3. Add more capabilities in this dialog or set permissions for Woo-commerce-related post types on the Post Types tab.
4. Change the role of the desired user to the new custom role you have just created.
When you create the new role, if you want the user to have no inherent capabilities (allowing you to add specific capabilities with Access), do not select any role to copy privileges from. This will give no permissions to the role and you will be able to add all capabilities manually.

In case you want to give users the same capabilities as authors (being able to write and edit their own content), select to copy privileges from Author role. To create users who can edit any content, select to copy privileges from Editor role. This setting will adjust the capabilities for content editing, so you can just set the Woo-commerce capabilities manually.

Comment: I've done what you explained exactly but using the Members plugin as mentioned in the original question.  I have updated the question with further details showing the capabilities granted etc.

Comment: I have cloned the Editor role, and copied over the permissions from the Shop manager role.